# I get a SQL error #1064 but dont know why

Tags: sql, database

I have created a table and want to use it while inserting data, however, it meets the error 1064 which I do not know the reason for.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE recursive_insert(IN max_val INT)
BEGIN
    WHILE i < max_val DO
        INSERT into app_user(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`gender`,`password`,`age`,`location`)
        VALUES(CONCAT('sure',i),'12354@gmail.com',CONCAT('18',FLOOR(RAND()*((999999999)+1000000000))),FLOOR(RAND()*2),UUID(),FLOOR(RAND()*100),'washington');
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

The Error message is shown like:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your TiDB version for the right syntax to use line 1 column
> 16 near "PROCEDURE recursive_insert(IN max_val INT)
> BEGIN
> WHILE i < max_val DO
> INSERT into
> app_user(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`gender`,`password`,`age`,`location`)
> VALUES(CONCAT('user',i),'12354@qq.com',CONCAT('18',FLOOR(RAND()*
> ((999999999)+1000000000))),FLOOR(RAND()*2),UUID(),FLOOR(RAND()*100),'深
> 圳');
> END WHILE;
> END"

Comment: Is `'深 圳'` supposed to be washington?

Comment: Remove some stuff step-wise, and see when the error disappears. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Probably not the immediate problem you are seeing, but you don’t appear to be giving i an initial value or incrementing it anywhere - so I’m not sure what you are expecting your WHILE loop to do

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, the stored procedure you created has a syntax error, which prevents it from being created successfully. Specifically, the error message indicates that there is a syntax error near line 1 column 16.

Based on the stored procedure code you provided, I noticed that the `WHILE` loop uses the variable `i` but it is not initialized. Therefore, you need to add the statement `DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;` in the stored procedure to initialize the variable `i` before it can be used in the loop.

In addition, you used the Chinese characters 深圳 in the `VALUES` clause, which may cause encoding issues. It is recommended that you modify it to English characters or use UTF-8 encoding.

Therefore, you can try modifying the stored procedure code as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE recursive_insert(IN max_val INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < max_val DO
        INSERT INTO app_user(`name`, `email`, `phone`, `gender`, `password`, `age`, `location`)
        VALUES(CONCAT('user', i), '12354@gmail.com', CONCAT('18', FLOOR(RAND() * ((999999999) + 1000000000))), FLOOR(RAND() * 2), UUID(), FLOOR(RAND() * 100), 'washington');
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

This stored procedure will insert `max_val` rows into the `app_user` table, where the name field starts with user followed by a number. Each time a row is inserted, a random phone and gender field, a random age field, and a fixed location field are generated. Meanwhile, the email and password fields are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

TiDB doesn't support stored procedures as documented [here](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/mysql-compatibility). Alternatives would be to use a CTE like in the example below or to use a external script.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1(id) SELECT n FROM (
     >   WITH RECURSIVE cte(n) AS (
     >     SELECT 1
     >     UNION ALL
     >     SELECT n+1 FROM CTE WHERE n<10
     >   ) SELECT * FROM cte
     > ) a;
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> TABLE t1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```